# Plotting a 3d Plot with multiple csv files that have the same pattern in R

Tags: r, csv, plotly, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to 3D Plot my multiple csv files.
Each csv file contains an axis coordinate (X, Y, Z). I use plotly to plot the 3D.

There are 15 CSV Files and I have to skip 6 Rows.
The name of CSV files:

1. 27383_Pos_1.csv
2. 63826_Pos_2.csv
   3....

I would like to extract the X Y Z values from minimum force and maximum force as well.

How to export it and name each files?

The pattern supposed to be "Pos_"

I would like to give the name for each points.

I have an example of the results but I have to manipulate the data from excel.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: We need more information. Do you want to plot each csv separately or join all of them?could you share some data or the code you have written so we can try it?

Comment: Hallo Cecelia, each csv contains X, Y, Z values (with the same name of coloum X, Y, Z. Because there are 15 CSV Files, it means, there are 15 Points, I would like to plot those 15 Points in 3D Plot. Thanks!